# Linear Programming (Approach)

Tags: linear-programming

A chemical manufacturer manufactures 2 types of chemical, A and B. Manager informs that the company has a maximum of 504 manpower hours in a week while having a minimum of 5000 litres of ingredient X. A and B contribute to 60% and 40% of the total company profit.

A would require 2,500 litres of the ingredient and 287 manpower hours in order to be produced and B would require 210 manpower hours and 2,980 litres of the ingredient in order to be produced.

Formulate the problem as a linear programming model.

My attempt,

We would want to maximize $0.6A+0.4B$ with the constraint of

$$2500A+2980B\geq5000$$
$$287A+210B\leq504$$

Is my approach correct? As I'm confused with the term 'minimum' and 'maximum'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have forgotten that $A,B\geq 0$. With it the simplex method can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

for me, it seems correct. 
the constraints are perfectly formulated, and the profit is precise.

Comment: Thanks for checking!